# Why is boostrap.js not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the following code in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venomoustoad/aefz4/) - it works, however, this does not work on my own local computer.

What could be the reason?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    

<input type="button" id="loading-example-btn" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary" value = "loading state">

<script>    
  $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
      var btn = $(this)
      btn.button('loading')    
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to load jQuery _before_ Bootstrap. JSFiddle is most likely doing this for you. If you bothered to check your dev console you'd probably see errors about `$` not being defined

Comment: Is `<script href="%BOOTSTRAP%"></script>` valid? Try with `<script src="%BOOTSTRAP%"></script>` instead (`href` vs `src`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**script** tag does not have href attribute. It contains src attribute.

so

```
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'> </script>
```

will work.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write your jQuery script inside `doucment.ready` function also you have loaded jQuery library after `booststrap.js`, this should be loaded before

try this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<input type="button" id="loading-example-btn" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary" value = "loading state">    

<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

      $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.button('loading')

      });
    });
</script>
```